# Rails 3, update data using selection from select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I am all new to rails, however quite familiar with "regular" MVC programming like Spring and .net. I am trying to cope with all this new way of doing stuff, but I keep getting stuck - especially when it comes to rendering/refreshing the same view with different data, based on a selection a user has made.

This is properly all really simple, and I can see it has been asked a lot of times - although, I cant seem to find any definite and "this is the rails way of doing it" answer.

All I want to do is the like this:

Database "scheme", with table a,b,c and their references:
C -> A
C -> B

Based on a selection of B in a drop down, I want to show all the "A's Cs" - dont mind the querying part, that is straight forward.
By now I choose the first B as a "first render" of the page in my controller, but when the user selects another B in the dropdown, the view should be rerendered based on the selection...
I dont want to use custom javascript filling or some other "weird" way. I must be possible to select something and refresh the view based on the selection in RoR.

I hope you either can help me or point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all these select lists in a form and in the 'onchange' event of the lists add javascript that submits the form ($('form_name').submit()). Once you submit the form, you have all the selected values as params (params[:select_list_1], params[:select_list_2]). Process them as you want, fire queries and display the view again.

You could submit the form to the same action. The action would be something like this:

```
def index
  if !request.post?
    # Generate default values
  else
    # Generate new resultset based on params
  end
end
```

EDIT (Form example): The form can be added as and :url specifies the action of form element:

```
<%= form_for(:select_list_form, :url => {:controller => "my_controller", :action => "index"}) do |f| %>
<!-- Your select list here -->
    <%= f.submit "Continue", :class => "form-button form-left" %>
<% end %>
<!-- Render data based on your instance variables -->
```

Comment: Of course not! -Just havent made it work yet :P
Could you please show some more code? I can get the form to submit properly.. If I submit it, it complains that I have no create method - i know its standard crud, but I need not create anything here...
Ive got a select tag inside a form_tag action => my_action.

Comment: And by the way, its only one select box, that updates a table of data based on the selection :)

Comment: So, I got it to work! But can it really be true, that a form submission always tries to call the create action? How to avoid this...??

Comment: No. The form calls the action that you specify. Have a look at the edit. I am adding a generic form. If you are adding a form to a model you can improve on it. Complete reference can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: Well, I think we are getting even closer now - however, I tried that, and got lost in the views needed to perform this action. Since I only want to redisplay the current view. 
Like this:  
User gets index.erb.html, to which index action is called. This fills a collection based on a "default" value.
User changes something in the dropdown, the "default" value is overwritten with the selected value, data is fetched from the database (stored in the same instance variable as used in index action)
The same view is rendered again, with the new data.
Specifying an action requies a view of that name?

Comment: As I had mentioned earlier, submit the form to the same action and generate data based on whether it is a get request(first request) or a post request (other subsequent requests). I have edited the code above to reflect the same.

Comment: Thanks - its working now. Just had to wrap my head around the rails way of thinking. I marked your answer as solution, but I cant opvote, since I have reputation < 15...

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter this problem myself and the cleanest way I have found is to use this :

- http://www.prototypejs.org/api/timedObserver/form-observer

It call an ajax request when the select list change. Then you have to set up an new action in your controller for example load_related :

```
def load_related
    @childreen = Model.where(....)
    render :update do |page|
         page.replace 'div id where you whant stuff to appear', :partial => '...'
    end
end
```

That's your first ajax request in Rails. For documentation :

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html